# Select option doesn't update in Vue JS with Chosen plugin And API

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-chosen

I am new to VueJS and have been trying to learn things from the docs and resources available on the net.

I have been trying to make VueJS run with Chosen Plugin in JS. So, my code initiates a vue app and also initiates a Select option with chosen plugin. The options in the select element are rendered using a `v-for` as shown below.

```
<select class="chosen-select">
    <option selected>Choose user...</option>
    <option v-for="(item,index) in users.data" :value="item.key">{{item.user}}</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({width:"100%"});
</script>
```

I make an API call to fetch the data from DB and update `user.data`:

```
$.get("demo_test.php", function(res, status){
    ...
    var newUserData = res.users;
    app.users.data.push(newUserData );   // here app is the Vue app
    ...
  });
```

I can see that the data has been updated in `app.user.data` but the select don't show up the new users in the list.

What should i do? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Due to reactivity limitations in JS, Vue cannot detect changes made to an array.

You can either use the `Vue.set(array, index, item)` to set the value of a specific index in the array to a new value OR in your case change the reference of your `users.data` array to a new array as follows:

```
$.get("demo_test.php", function(res, status){
    ...
    var newUserData = res.users;
    app.users.data = [...app.users.data, newUserData];
    ...
  });
```

The above code should trigger the change as `app.users.data` now points to a new array that's a copy of the existing array with the new item added to it.